# Eclipse Java Build Directory

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Something driving me crazy - I have autobuild set in java eclipse ide and its building to a JAR apparently. Where is the output directory??

I don't see any build folders or anything in the project home folder.

Thanks,
Kidovate

Comment: Hmm, what is used for building? Ant? If so, you should check the `build.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you examining the project folder? Many of the Eclipse navigation views filter out output folders. Take a look at your project directory with you OS file system browser instead.

The java output directories are configured via Project Properties -> Java Build Path. You can go to that page to see what folders are being currently used.

Note that Eclipse java build does not generate a jar. It generates a directory of classes. To generate a jar, you have to invoke File -> Export -> Jar File wizard or use an external script like ant or maven.

Answer (score 4):

By default this is **bin/** sub-directory of your project's directory, **bin/classes** will contain *.class* files, **bin/** itself will contain *.jar* if you build it explicitly (e.g. via File/Export...). If you have m2eclipse installed and this is maven project then target directory will be **target/**.